# In jQuery is it more efficient to use filter(), or just do so in the each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, each

I currently have code that is pulling in data via jQuery and then displaying it using the `each` method.

However, I was running into an issue with sorting, so I looked into using, and added, jQuery's `filter` method before the `sort` (which makes sense).

I'm now looking at removing the `sort`, and am wondering if I should leave the `filter` call as-is, or move it back into the `each`.

The examples in the [jQuery API documentation for filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) stick with styling results, not with the output of textual content (specifically, not using `each()`).

The documentation currently states that "[t]he supplied selector is tested against each element [...]," which makes me believe that doing a `filter` *and* an `each` would result in non-filtered elements being looped through twice, versus only once if the check was made solely in the `each` loop.

Am I correct in believing that is more efficient?

EDIT: Dummy example.

So this:

```
// data is XML content
data = data.filter(function (a) {
    return ($(this).attr('display') == "true");
});
data.each(function () {
    // do stuff here to output to the page
});
```

Versus this:

```
// data is XML content
data.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('display') == "true") {
        // do stuff here to output to the page
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps.. you should paste some code..

Comment: Why not test the performance difference yourself?

Comment: James, could you give a very small and concise code snippet for the code structure that you're referring to? It'll make it easier to visualize your question :)

Comment: @Russ cam , is there any place to check performance..

Comment: @kobe http://jsperf.com/ will seemingly let you, but I personally found the UI to be confusing.

Comment: I'm suggesting using [XPath(?) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Exactly as you said:

> The documentation currently states
>   that *"the supplied selector is
>   tested against each element [...]"*,
>   which makes me believe that doing a
>   filter and an each would result in
>   non-filtered elements being looped
>   through twice, versus only once if the
>   check was made solely in the each
>   loop.

Through your code we can clearly see that you are using `each` in both cases, what is already a *loop*. And the `filter` by itself is another *loop* (with an *if* it for filtering). That is, we are comparing performance between **two loops** with **one loop**. Inevitably **less loops = better performance**.

I created [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/CrQs8/1/) and profiled with [Firebug Profiling Tool](http://getfirebug.com/javascript). As expected, the **second option** *with only one loop* is **faster**. Of course with this small amount of elements the difference was only 0.062ms. But obviously the difference would **increase linearly** with more elements.

Since many people are super worried to say the difference is small and you should choose according to the maintainability, I feel free to express my opinion: I also agree with that. In fact I think the more maintainable code is without the filter, but it's only a matter of taste. Finally, your question was about what was more efficient and this is what was answered, although the difference is small.

Comment: actually the running time would increase linearly with the number of elements. Two loops is just a constant multiple (c=2) of the number of elements.

Comment: It would increase *linearly* (or perhaps, worse case, polynomial-ly).  And think about how incredible short a time 0.062ms is. It's one sixteen-thousanth of a second!  If you had a machine making a click every 0.062ms, the resulting whine would be so high-pitched only a dog could hear it!

Comment: You are right, it's linearly. But the important here is: increases. The question clearly asks what has better performance. Less 0.062ms is better performance. If it's something that the OP must take care, it's her choice. The answer must be only to answer her question: what is more efficient.

Comment: +1 @ErickPetru, congratulations! You answered the question, explained the reasons, demonstrated numerical results confirming it and moreover used great arguments! If I could done more than one vote here...

Comment: You've said exactly what I was hoping to hear. To me, doing the filter in the each just makes more sense. But, if there was a vast difference between the two, and filter was in some way more efficient ... then that's what I would have implemented.

Answer (score 10):

You are correct that using filter and each is slower. It is faster to use just the each loop. Where possible do optimise it to use less loops.

But this is a micro optimisation. This should only be optimised when it's "free" and doesn't come at a cost of readable code. I would personally pick to use one or the other based on a style / readability preference rather then on performance.

Unless you've got a huge sets of DOM elements you won't notice the difference (and if you do then you've got bigger problems).

And if you care about this difference then you care about not using jQuery because jQuery is slow.

What you should care about is readability and maintainability.

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
    // get elements I care about
}).each(function() {
    // deal with them
});
```

vs

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    // get elements I care about
    if (condition) {
         // deal with them
    }
}
```

Whichever makes your code more readable and maintainable is the optimum choice. As a separate note filter is a lot more powerful if used with `.map` then if used with `.each`.

Let me also point out that optimising from two loops to one loop is optimising from `O(n)` to `O(n)`. That's not something you should care about. In the past I also feel that it's "better" to put everything in one loop because you only loop once, but this really limits you in using map/reduce/filter.

Write meaningful, self-documenting code. Only optimise bottlenecks.

Comment: This. "What you should care about is readability and maintainability."   It's extraordinarily rare that one micro-optimization like this makes any user-detectable difference and when it happens, it's extraordinarily easy to detect and fix.  The OP should look at the two code skeletons Raynos provided and ask himself which of the two better conveys the actual meaning of the code.  "It's easier to optimize correct code than to correct optimized code."

Comment: @Malvolio exactly. Write what allows the code to be most self documenting in terms of what it does and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: True, it's a micro optimization, but I'd much rather know the 'correct'/more efficient way to do something, and get used to doing it that way, than not. +1

Comment: @JamesSkemp The correct way is the single loop. What you have to be careful with is condensing 3 readable loops into one big loop with lots of messy logic "just because one loop is faster". I simply want to point out that this is not something you should worry about too much. Of course where possible make it use less loops but worry about readable code first.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the performance here to be very similar, with the each being slightly faster (probably noticeable in large datasets where the filtered set is still large).  Filter probably just loops over the set anyway (someone correct me if I'm wrong).  So the first example loops the full set and then loops the smaller set.  The 2nd just loops once.

However, if possible, the fastest way would be to include the filter in your initial selector.  So lets say your current data variable is the result of calling `$("div")`.  Instead of calling that and then filtering it, use this to begin with:

```
$("div[display='true']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't worry about micro-optimizations like this since in the grand scheme of things, you'll likely have a lot more to worry about in terms of performance than jQuery `.each()` vs. `.filter()`, but to answer the question at hand, you should be able to get the best results using one `.filter()`:

```
data.filter(function() {
  return ($(this).attr('display')==="true");
}).appendTo($('body'));
```

For a primitive performance comparison between `.each()` and `.filter()`, you can check out this codepen:

http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/LWpwwa

However, if all you're trying to do is output all nodes with `display="true"` to the page, then you can simply do as suggested by James Montagne (assuming the node is `<element>`):

```
$('element[display=true]').appendTo($('body'));
```